# What is "routined" and why is it eating my CPU?

Tags: macos, cpu

After my fans started blazing, I checked top and found that a process named routined was using 60-70% cpu. Surprisingly, I found no information about this process via Google, other than a mention of it in relation to a keychain issue which doesn't apply to me.

Anybody know what this process is doing?

The process was owned by my user, but after killing it, it came back running as root. After a minute or so, the cpu usage droped to 0.

macOS Catalina 10.15.2 on a MacBook Pro

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/7lcbyx/checking_whether_an_executable_is_part_of/ might help?

Comment: Thanks. It is signed by Apple, but I'm just curious about what it does, and why it suddenly decided to go crazy.

Comment: Seems like it could be location tracking https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2018/06/apple-probably-knows-what-you-did-last-summer not sure why it should be chewing up CPU though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of disabling *routined,* try this:

In your home directory, go look inside *~/Library/Preferences*.  Is there a *com.apple.routined.plist* file there?  Delete this plist file & restart your Mac.

One more thing:

If you are using a firewall like Little Snitch, be sure *routined* has outgoing network access.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 16):

I wondered the same thing! It does have a small but somewhat helpful man page, which you can get via `man routined` in Terminal.

```
NAME
     routined -- A daemon that learns the historical location patterns of a user.

DESCRIPTION
     routined is a per-user daemon that learns historical location patterns of a user and predicts
     future visits to locations.

     There are no configurations to routined, and users should not run routined manually.
```

As to what it's doing? One way to find this out for (nearly) any process is to take a sample using Activity Monitor:

[image: Activity Monitor Sample]

That will then produce a fairly verbose report that you can send to Apple using Feedback Assistant: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

In my sample, it appears to be training a machine learning model:

```
 +               1440 __44-[RTLearnedLocationEngine trainWithHandler:]_block_invoke  (in libcoreroutine.dylib) + 475  [0x7fff6ff29e85]
    +                 1440 -[RTLearnedLocationEngine _trainWithHandler:]  (in libcoreroutine.dylib) + 1041  [0x7fff6ff29612]
    +                   1440 -[RTLearnedLocationEngine _trainWithFromDate:ToDate:forLastLearnedVisit:handler:]  (in libcoreroutine.dylib) + 765  [0x7fff6ff2996a]
    +                     1440 -[RTLearnedLocationEngine _trainLocationsOfInterestModelWithError:]  (in libcoreroutine.dylib) + 121  [0x7fff6ff2a1f7]
    +                       1440 -[RTLearnedLocationEngine _relabelWithError:]  (in libcoreroutine.dylib) + 303  [0x7fff6ff2e58e]
    +                         1440 -[RTLearnedLocationEngine _relabelWithRelabeler:relabelerPersister:error:]  (in libcoreroutine.dylib) + 1619  [0x7fff6ff2ec22]
    +                           1440 -[RTLearnedLocationStore enumerateStoredLocationsOfInterestWithOptions:enumerationBlock:]  (in libcoreroutine.dylib)
```

I would expect such activity to eventually complete and stop chewing CPU, but you never know!

Comment: That explains what it does.  Why does my mac try to predict my location?  As far as I can tell, it's not offering me any useful functionality on that basis.

Answer (score 1):

So just to close this off, it seems like routined has something to do with location tracking. But I don't know why it suddenly started using a lot of CPU.

Comment: been blowing up my CPU too, 10.15.3 on an older mac mini.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and installing the combo update https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2030 has solved it for me.

**Update:**

I have been too optimistic about the combo update because after a few days I noticed it didn't actually solved it for me and ended up completely disabling the service. Do the following:

```
sudo mount -rw /
sudo mv /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.routined.plist /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.routined.plist.disabled
```

Then reboot the system.

Comment: I am already at 10.15.3 as I am currently experiencing 100% cpu for routined. But the cpu usage went down a short while after waking up my MacBook.